# Inhomogeneous Cauchy–Riemann equation on complex plane with continous right hand side

Tags: cv.complex-variables

Consider the equation $\bar{\partial} f=g$ on the complex plane. We may assume $g$ is compactly supported, but we need the case that $g$ is only assumed to be continuous. Is there a solution to this equation? (I mean classical solution.) If yes, is it the solution given by Cauchy integral formula?

1. If $g$ is $C^1$, then we can find the answer from almost all textbooks.
2. I tried to use an approximation method, but failed to find the correct estimate.

It seems to me that the answer is yes and is widely known to experts.

Comment: Sometimes ago [I dealt with this problem in a somewhat extended way](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3125765/let-h-mathbbc-to-mathbbc-in-ck-mathbbc-with-compact-support-find/3137198#3137198). I analyzed the problem under the hypothesis that $\operatorname{supp} g$ is compact and $g\in C^k$, $k \le 1$ but, as I wrote in the notes section of my answer, the methods I used work also with non compact and non smooth right hand side (I gave precise references illustrating these points).

Comment: I followed your link and checked the reference therein. The theorem provides us with a solution in the _distribution_ sense. We want to know if there is a classical one. @Daniele

Comment: In my former answer two solutions are presented: the second one is a distribution theory based one (or PDE based, using the words of the OP), while the first one involves only tools from classical complex analysis (namely the Cauchy-Green formula in the complex plane) and is adapted from a proof given by Henkin and Leiterer (reference cited there) which deal with the more difficult case where $g\in C^0$ and is not compactly supported.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The integral operator
$$Ph(z)=-\frac{1}{\pi}\int\int h(\zeta)\left(\frac{1}{\zeta-z}-\frac{1}{z}\right)dxdy$$
acts on $L^p$, $p>2$, and the result satiafies $(Ph)_{\overline{z}}=h$
in the sense of distributions. For continuous $h$, this equation may not
have a classical $C^1$ solution.

Edit. The following example was suggested by user @Fedja.
It is known that $(Ph)_z=Th,$ where $T$ is the following operator:
$$Th(z)=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\left(-\frac{1}{\pi}\int\int_{|\zeta-z|>\epsilon}\frac{h(\zeta)}{(z-\zeta)^2}dxdy\right).$$
So taking
$f=Ph$, with
$$h(z)=\frac{z^2}{|z|^2\log|z|},$$
which is continuous,
we obtain $f_z(0)=\infty$, so $f$ is not in $C^1$.

Reference for these two operators $P$ and $T$ is L. Ahlfors, Lectures on quasiconformal mappings, Chap. V, A.

Comment: Thank you very much @Eremenko. Motivated by your $h$, we may just consider $f(z)=z \log (-\log |z|^2)$ and verify the claim directly.